# apns token is not unique

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, token, voip

I am working on an application and I encountered such a problem: after uninstalling and installing a new application, when authorizing a new user, the token of the previous user is stored, which was authorized on the device before uninstallation. The token for VoIP push remains the same and when I call the previous user, a voip call comes to both users due to the same token. I was looking for this moment in the manual APNS, but could not find anything.
Is it possible that the platform does not perform any necessary actions before requesting a token?
iphone: 5se

Comment: you need to send apns token to server every time when doing authorization or logging in again.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan Sorry, maybe I misunderstood you. I save tokens in the db during authorization, but the fact is that when authorizing and receiving a "new" token from APNS, it returns the same token that the previous user of this device had. Thus, I have two users with the same tokens and device_id in the database. If the user came out correctly, then the cleaning would be done for him, but I need to take into account such a case when he did not and just uninstalled the application

Comment: nope when sending token why dont you check if same token already exist? 
as now device belong to new user 
so logout the previous user remove his token and ask him(old user) to authorize himself again.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan Thank you for wasting your time. But unfortunately we can’t search all existing users to check all available tokens of each user